# How to end and save Java Flight Recorder recording in Java Mission Control when application ends?

Tags: java, performance, performance-testing, jfr, java-mission-control

I am currently using Java Mission Control (JMC) to profile my application's performance with the Java Flight Recorder (JFR) plugin.

I know how to set up JFR on the command line to record from the beginning to the end of the application duration. However, I do not know how to do it when using the JFR plugin in JMC. Is this something that is possible in JMC? Or am I only able to do this on the command line?

And to better describe the current dilemma, when my application ends, JMC pops up a warning dialog saying that the JVM ended unexpectedly, and then from there, I lose my recording.

[image: A screenshot of the warning dialog that says "Problem while monitoring recording My Recording on [21] ConnectFour.Main (27280). The monitored JVM might have been terminated." -- further down on the dialog is a checked checkbox that says "Show warnings for problems that occur while monitoring flight recordings."]

I'm sure the answer to this is relatively simple, but I don't see any easily accessible resources that provide the answer.

**EDIT** - I am aware of how to start a recording on JMC using JFR, that's not my question here. My question is how do I get the command line benefits (record the whole application's life time, and then save the recording upon application close) on JMC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click in the JVM Browser and select "Start Flight Recording ...", specify the amount of time you want the recording to be, for example 10 minutes. When the recording is finished, recording data is transferred and displayed in JMC.

If the application exits before the specified time, the recording will be lost. You will have to make sure the application doesn't exit, or specify a shorter recording time, or start the recording from command line and open the file.

Comment: You have just described to me my current situation and my failed attempts. It is doing exactly what you described that prompted to me to ask my question. I want to be able to record the FULL application's lifetime, and have the recording automatically close once the application does. I'll edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: It's not possible. Once the application exits, the connection to JMC is dropped, and the file can't be retrieved.

Comment: To confirm, are you telling me that it's not possible to do in JMC ***at all***? If so, can you point me to some documentation saying that, or are you getting that from the lack of options in JMC? Either way, if it really is true that JMC is able to do what I described, I'll award you the bounty. But I'm going to wait the full duration to make absolutely sure. That said, could you edit your answer to reflect this new information? If we're going to say it is not possible, let's lead with that, and then the rest of your original answer will be a good workaround for that lack of functionality.

Comment: Especially that "start the recording from the command line and open the file", that's definitely the best of your list of options. I'd appreciate it if you could start your answer with that suggestion after mentioning that it is not possible to do in JMC alone.

Comment: When the process is dead, the Java class implementing the FlightRecorderMXBean can't execute. It's no different than you can't transfer a HTML page after a web server has exited.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, ty vm. I'll still wait the time, in case someone knows of some plugin that you can add to it to make it work as desired, but you have convinced me.

Comment: Lol, I see now that you are someone who helped build JFR. In that case, I'll award the bounty now and accept the answer. Apologies.